# How to use getActivity in a fragment started by a WearableActivity in Android?

Tags: android-fragments, wear-os

I have a WearableActivity as my main activity and I want to use fragments for different layouts. The trouble is when I try to get a reference to the main activity using getActivity() in the fragment, Android Studio says that I cannot cast from FragmentActivity to my MainWearActivity(which extends WearableActivity).

My MainWearActivity class:

```
public class MainWearActivity extends WearableActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private WatchViewStub mContainerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wear);
        mContainerView = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);
        mContainerView.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub watchViewStub) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
        super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbient() {
        super.onUpdateAmbient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitAmbient() {
        super.onExitAmbient();
    }
}
```

My fragment class:

```
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_fragment, container, false);

        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity(); // ERROR HERE

        return view;
    }
}
```

When I try to the result of cast getActivity() to my main activity it won't allow me. Can anyone help me to get around this? I need a reference to my main activity so that I can use it as a context. Thanks

**EDIT**

String's answer below solved the problem. An additional note I'd like to add however, is that if you are using the fragment pager adapter, you will have to add "compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'" to your build.gradle, and use the support v13 pager adapter which allows you to return an android.app.Fragment from GetItem().

Comment: What does the layout that contains your NavigationFragment look like? Are you adding the NavigationFragment directly to the MainWearActivity or a different activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `NavigationFragment` an instance of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, by any chance? I'm guessing so, because that's the `Fragment` class that expects `getActivity()` to return a `FragmentActivity`.

If my guess is correct, what you need to do is find the line in your `NavigationFragment.java` file that reads:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and change it to

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

You may need to change a few other imports and calls similarly, to remove reference to the support library and its classes. But there's no need to be using support fragments on Wear - all the devices are well new enough to have fragments natively.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider` instead of using `WearableActivity`.

It is the new preferred method and it still gives you the `onEnterAmbient()`, `onAmbientUpdate()`, and `onExitAmbient()` but also lets you use `Activity` (or any sub classes... FragementActivity, etc.). It also allows you to support the Architecture components.

[Official docs call out the details](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html).